# Conectar SQL server y Onedrive

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Estimado gurús, saben si existe alguna forma de conectar Microsoft SQL Server con OneDrive (y viceversa) de tal forma de que se pueda modificar y actualizar datos de celdas en tiempo real?

NOTA: No me sirve el File Task Transfer, ya que la tabla lo estaría visualizando y modificando 6 personas a la vez por lo que la conexión debería se directa e independiente.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: conectar SQL Server con qué en OneDrive?, con archivos planos?, Excel?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)

Comment: @Lamak En realidad, podría ser un csv u otro archivo, el problema es que se tiene mas de un millón de registros por lo que se haría muy pesado y lento para modificar, mas aún si se tiene 6 personas trabajando en el mismo archivo.

Comment: @Alfabravo Pero la pregunta es simple, no detallo más porque las respuestas amplias son las que me servirían, ya que estoy abierto a que me digan si se puede realizar la tarea mediante en SSIS, algun programa externo, configuración en la nube, etc.

Comment: Vuelve y revisa cómo preguntar en el enlace que te compartí. Tú buscas respuestas infinitas y no tenemos idea de qué estás intentando ni cómo. El sitio no es un foro ni apunta a preguntas con respuestas infinitas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.